# Return array of strings from MVC to jQuery ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, arrays, system.array

I want to return an array of strings from an MVC function via a jQuery AJAX call.

My client side code is:

```
function get_categories() {
    var url = "/Profile/GetCharacters";
    $.post(url, function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

But I cannot read array elements. In `alert(data)` it always says `system.array[]`
and in `alert(data[0])` it says `s` (i.e. first character in system.array[]) and not the array elements.

Here is simplified version of my server side code.. cause original is big way too complicated  :)

```
public Array GetCharacters()
    {

        var ret = new string[10];
        ret[0]="abc";
        ret[1] = "def";
        ret[2] = "ghi";
        return (ret);
    }
```

but this gives "System.string[]" instead and same problem when accessing individual values

Comment: Why not return JSON and parse that?

Comment: Please post your server side code (your action method). I think you're returning a string containing `system.array[]`, rather than a JSON serialized array.

Comment: im not using json which is my plan B if this doesn't work out

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can return JSON.

For instance, you could make an Ajax request to the following controller action:

```
public JsonResult GetMyData()
{
    SomeClass s = new SomeClass();
    s.Property1 = "value";
    s.Property2 = "another value";

    return Json(s, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //you will need the AllowGet option to return data to a GET request
}
```

Then, your javascript could make an Ajax request (using jQuery's Ajax function) to the controller:

```
var onSuccess = function (data) {
    //data will be your s object, in JSON format
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/ControllerName/GetMyData/',
    success: function (data) { onSuccess(data); }
});
```

**EDIT:** When returning an array, or List you will need to add the traditional:true option to the Ajax call, like this:

```
var onSuccess = function (data) {
    //data will be your s object, in JSON format
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/ControllerName/GetMyData/',
    success: function (data) { onSuccess(data); },
    traditional: true
});
```

I am not 100% sure why (I Iam sure someone will fill us in), but that has given me fits in the past.

**One more EDIT**: You may need to parse the JSON, which should create an actual javascript Array object for you:

```
var onSuccess = function (data) {
    //data will be your s object, in JSON format
    var arr = JSON.parse(data);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you running on your backend side?

Basically you may want to serialize your array first using json or xml.

If it's PHP, here is an example from [jQuery .post API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Example: Posts to the test.php page and gets contents which has been returned in json format.

PHP code

`<?php echo json_encode(array("name"=>"John","time"=>"2pm")); ?>`

jQuery code

```
$.post("test.php", { "func": "getNameAndTime" },
 function(data){
   console.log(data.name); // John
   console.log(data.time); //  2pm
 }, "json");
```

If it's JAVA you can use a library to serialize json objects like [Googles' gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)